# How to FULLY install Android Studio to a non-default (D:) drive

Tags: android, installation

I'm going to start with the high-level "common sense" question and then get into the tech details:

The high-level question:  When running the Android Studio installation program in Windows 10, and I tell it to install to D: drive (instead of the default C: drive), why does it insist on installing some components onto the C: drive?

Reasons for installing to a non-default drive:

---

1. Brand new high-performance gaming laptops, such as my ASUS Republic Of Gamers, come pre-installed with Windows 10 and two drives:  A C: drive labeled "OS" and a D: drive labeled "DATA".  The C: drive has just enough room for Windows 10 plus some buffer for future "OS" upgrades.  The D: drive is orders of magnitude larger.

The obvious intent was for all third-party (non-OS) programs to live on D: drive, or at least not on C: "OS" drive. (I will ignore the "separation of 'code' and 'data' design paradigm, which would rightfully require a third P: 'PROGRAM' drive, and I'll just focus on the lack-of-space problem.)

2. Reading over the other stackoverflow questions by searching for "android install d drive" yield several hits, which talk around this higher-level concept, but are about more detailed issues, such as where to put the jdk and/or the sdk, missing  gradle libraries, tinkering with environment variables and such, but the central theme in them appears (to me at least) to be about putting the IDE on the d: drive (fully or partially), and the consequent errors encountered while attempting that.

### The bottom line is that apparently I'm not the only one with limited space on C: drive who had to struggle with the IDE install.

After 5 install/uninstall attempts, each time changing all "c:" text box prompts to "d:" and learning more and more about the various libraries and folders that STILL went to c: drive, I've finally found all the big ones, and set symbolic links for them, and moved their contents over to d: drive targets.

There are still a few "minor"(?) files and directories on c: drive that I'm not really sure belong to Android Studio, but I'm too chicken/lazy to set up the symbolic links for them...but here's my high-level question for the Android Studio developers:

WHY SHOULD I HAVE TO?  WHY CAN'T THIS BE MADE SIMPLE AND INTUITIVE? If I tell the install program to put EVERYTHING on the d: drive (IDE, sdk, jdk, gradle, emulator, and so on)  why can't the install program just do that?

Am I missing something simple here?  If I am missing something simple or obvious, then why does it (and my first app) build and run just fine if I set all these symbolic links to d: drive targets?

Comment: I haven't installed AS on Windows, but all the toolchain needed for it to work can be anywhere you want, including the binary of Android Studio. Worst case scenario you need to update your windows PATH so it can find Java and what not, but other than that, I don't see any reason why it couldn't go into d:/. Windows is different, it may need some components inside c:/windows/* or similar, which you cannot avoid. What did you try? What is in "c" that you don't want? How do you know this?

Comment: I don't want anything in c: drive having to do with Android Studio.  The reason has to do solely with lack of space on c: drive, which is already running low with just the Windows 10 OS on it.  If my c: drive was 10 times larger than my d: drive, instead of it being the other way around, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Be aware that I got it all working (as I said in my original post) by simply installing with symbolic links for (most) all the stuff that the installer put in c: drive.  I didn't have to tinker with the path or other environment variables.

Comment: To me, this smells like a "bug" in the installation, but maybe I'm missing something simple, so I wanted to ask the question on stackoverflow first, and I surely don't want to cause hurt feelings for the Android Studio developers.

Comment: Glad to hear you made it work. I don't have Windows, and I don't work for either Google or JetBrains, so no hard feelings. This ought to be a windows thing, because on Linux, I can drag and drop the unzipped Android Studio folder and run it from anywhere. The SDK path can be configured, the emulators are also anywhere you want, and the only thing it may go onto your /home is the user-configuration (as it should), so I honestly don't know what Windows needs.

Comment: Ya.  Makes sense.  I'm guessing it has to do with the Windows install executable. No worries.  I got it working anyway.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @BenEthridge How could you make it work without putting anything in drive C???

Comment: Great rant, but it'd be helpful if you could also answer the question so that it'll be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I highly agree with everything you said... I have limited space in my C:\ which is an SSD that boots up my system quickly.

Comment: Sahar Elgendy and ARV:  I may not have formally answered the question with the "Answer Your Question" button, but if you read my original post and my above comments, you can see how I got it working, so (a) that makes it not just a rant and (b) the question is essentially "answered" above.  That being said, the formal answer provided by Sumakha M below is apparently being up-voted so I'm thinking y'all should try that first?

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Change the default installation location of the programs to D or other required drive by using the following method:

1. Press Win+R
2. Type in regedit
3. Head to the following location:
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
4. You will find two files: ProgramFilesDir and ProgramFilesDir (x86)
5. Right click on the two names and click on Modify.
6. Change the drive name from C to whatever drive you want to make the installations.
7. Note that any and every software you install will get installed in the mentioned drive.

Comment: this has to be a joke right ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is now available through Portapps:

https://portapps.io/app/android-studio-portable/

Warning: portable apps have been used as an attack vector by malware distributors ...

https://www.mosse-security.com/advisories/advisory-2019-002-cyber-adversaries-use-portable-applications-supply-chain-attacks.html

Comment: https://portapps.io/doc/faq/ looks encouraging.