# How to install Android Studio on Windows 10 completely on a drive other than the default OS drive?

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

I am trying to install Android Studio 2020.3.1 on Windows 10.

The drive where my OS lives is the C: drive. This SSD drive has limited space, about 100 GB or so.

I need to install Android Studio FULLY on to a more spacious drive, say D:.

I can install the main Android Studio binaries by choosing the installation directory during install.

However, Android Studio **STILL** uses many large folders on my C: (on my %USER% directory), totaling to around 20+ GB and growing. I need it to fully use D: and not touch the C: . Moving things one by one tends to mess up the installation.

(This problem is mentioned here: [How to FULLY install Android Studio to a non-default (D:) drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347671/how-to-fully-install-android-studio-to-a-non-default-d-drive) , but unfortunately, that question is a rant and not a well posed question.)

Hence my question: how do I cause Android Studio to be FULLY installed on a non-default drive on Windows 10? I.e., D: and not (say) C:.

Comment: One potential solution is to move the entire %USERS% to the D:, but I'd rather not do this to avoid unintended consequences.

Comment: Actually, certain folders like .gradle and .android need to be present in the User directory. So, you can't fully move it.

Comment: I just upgraded my C: drive to 500 GB, so the problem has gone away, for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is why Android Studio occupies a lot of your C: disk space and will increase day by day. What you need to do is just move this folder out of C:, and retarget this SDK location to your new one. And don't forget to check your system envrionment to see if any old SDK location has been used, if true then replace them.
[image: Snap]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose specific drive for android SDK. You can choose specific drive for files required for Android Studio works, i.e. Program Files or Program Files (x86) into drive D, E... or any else. You Knows .graddle .m2 or another dependency managements need to be settings for uses and specific path.