# How to install Android Studio 2020.3.1 for Windows 64-bit completely on a drive other than C: Drive

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

## Problem

I am new to android development. I am trying to learn flutter and came to know that Android Studio(AS) is better than VS Code for android development.

The laptop I use has an `SSD(C:OS and E:Apps)` and a `Hard disk(D:)`. `C:` drive is almost full and can't accommodate Android Studio and all the dependency folders like the sdks, avd folder, graddle etc., So I want to install Android Studio and all other dependencies on the `E:` drive which has more than 300 GB of space. It is only due to lack of space on C: drive that I want to install Android Studio on E: drive.

### What I tried already

- Firstly I uninstalled AS manually (because uninstaller is not provided in newer versions) following this article on Reddit [Uninstall Android Studio Manually](https://www.reddit.com/user/Lamda-f90/comments/p44wkc/uninstall_android_studio_manually/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share).
- Then I installed it again but this time during installation, I changed the location where it saves SDKs and the AS itself to `E:` drive. This caused problems with Android Virtual Devices. So following another StackOverflow question, I added an environment variable named ANDROID_SDK_HOME but then I had an issue with AS not detecting `adb` (but I am able to access it from the command line).
- I searched for a solution on stack overflow. I saw this question on [How to FULLY install Android Studio to a non-default (D:) drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347671/how-to-fully-install-android-studio-to-a-non-default-d-drive) but it was over my head. If that's a valid solution, I would definitely like to know how to add those symbolic links.
- Currently, I have uninstalled AS again (manually) and I even deleted the env variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. I have flutter and dart installed.

---

I would like to know how I can install AS and dependencies completely on `E:` Drive and get it working along with the Android Virtual Device.

##### Note

Android Studio worked fine when it was on C: drive but C: drive doesn't have enough space to accommodate the growing size of AS and dependencies.

If I have to provide any other information about the current situation, please let me know in a comment rather than in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, I've used the jetbrains' toolbox to install android studio on my laptop. Maybe you could try it. this is the link -> https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/.

After install the AS with the toolbox, change the SDK's path when the dialog is prompted. That works for me.

Comment: Does it save all the dependency files also into E: Drive? That's the main motto. I will try this method for sure. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yep, I have the AS on my C: Drive and the SDK on my D: drive